Trigger to get a column value from tableA to tableB by select statement
Table1
CREATE TABLE `active_year` (
  `ActiveYearId` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  `StartYear` date NOT NULL,
  `EndYear` date NOT NULL,
  `ActiveId` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `active_year`(`ActiveYearId`, `StartYear`, `EndYear`, `ActiveId`) VALUES
('20222023','2022-01-01','2023-12-31',0);
INSERT INTO `active_year`(`ActiveYearId`, `StartYear`, `EndYear`, `ActiveId`) VALUES
('20232024','2023-01-01','2024-12-31',0);
INSERT INTO `active_year`(`ActiveYearId`, `StartYear`, `EndYear`, `ActiveId`) VALUES
('20242025','2024-01-01','2025-12-31',1);
----------------
Table 2
CREATE TABLE `sfs` (
`Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `ActiveYearId` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , 
`Name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
`Description` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `sfs` (`Id`, `ActiveYearId`, `Name`, `Description`) VALUES (NULL, '20242025', 'sam', 'Hero'), (NULL, '20242025', 'Draad', 'in process');
---------------


INSERT INTO `sfs` (`Id`, `ActiveYearId`, `Name`, `Description`) VALUES (NULL, '', 'sam', 'Hero');
 INSERT INTO `sfs` (`Id`, `ActiveYearId`, `Name`, `Description`) (NULL, '', 'Draad', 'in process');

When I insert data to table 2 like below :
INSERT INTO `sfs` (`Id`, `ActiveYearId`, `Name`, `Description`) VALUES (NULL, '', 'mical', 'Herro');
 INSERT INTO `sfs` (`Id`, `ActiveYearId`, `Name`, `Description`) (NULL, '', 'Tom', 'in process')

The value for column ActiveYearId will be added by the result of the (
SELECT `ActiveYearId` FROM `active_year` WHERE `ActiveId` = 1;
)

my trigger was :
create trigger `update_sfs` after insert on `sfs`
for each row 
begin
set new.ActiveYearId = (sELECT `ActiveYearId` FROM `active_year` WHERE `ActiveId` = 1);

end;

error : updating of new row is not allowed in after trigger
i am using Server version: 10.4.32-MariaDB

Try changing your update_sfs trigger to like below:
CREATE TRIGGER `update_sfs` BEFORE INSERT ON `sfs`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE active_year_id INT;    
    SELECT `ActiveYearId` INTO active_year_id 
    FROM `active_year`
    WHERE `ActiveId` = 1;
    SET NEW.ActiveYearId = active_year_id;

END

Refer to the attached dbfiddle

I did change the dbfiddle (but you reverted that change...) because in the current fiddle the AvtiveYearId is inserted.  I removed that from the INSERT statement, to make it more clear the values are inserted by the TRIGGER.   (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/QKZ6FmHv )

same issue my dear @SELA ... no data inserted to the ActiveYearId

@Abd: Please re-test, because this works, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/_hP6zzie

@Luuk ... yaa its worked ... the error in my Trigger was time (before or after ) ... thanks  support .. please How can I use dbfiddle ?
It's a good way to explain

@Abd appreciate if you can mark it as the correct answer and give an upvote for it.. for the contribution

@Abd: Go to: https://dbfiddle.uk/ and choose the database you want. The URL changes for every change you make.

@Luuk many thanks
